# Braces placement in object definition in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, code-formatting

Is there any way to make PhpStorm place curly brackets on new line in this situation?

```
var test = {
                '*':
                {
                    // something
                }
            }
```

instead of making this (after reformatting):

```
var test = {
                '*': {
                    // something
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible. Please vote for [WEB-15263](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15263) and linked ticket